# Remove event listener inside promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am defining an event listener within a promise. The code works but I do not know how to remove the event listener. In the example, a promise is not used. However, I need to use the promise to wait for the audio to stop playing before playing the next audio. I am using react-native-sound-player.

This is my code:

```
 const playSound = async url => {
    try {
      const sound = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      SoundPlayer.addEventListener('FinishedPlaying', ({ success }) => {
      console.log('finished playing', success)
      resolve(success)      
      })}); 
    SoundPlayer.playSoundFile(url, 'mp3');
    await sound
    SoundPlayer.stop()
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(`cannot play the sound file`, e);
    }
  };
```

This is how the package example would remove the eventListener:

```
const playSound = url => {
    try {
      const sound = SoundPlayer.addEventListener('FinishedPlaying', ({ success }) => {
      console.log('finished playing', success)
      resolve(success)      
      })
    SoundPlayer.playSoundFile(url, 'mp3');
    
    SoundPlayer.stop()
    sound.remove()
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(`cannot play the sound file`, e);
    }
  };
```

But this would not work for my use case since I need to wait for the audio to finish playing before I can move onto the next audio. How can I remove the eventListener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're not using what is returned from `.addEventListener`. According to the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sound-player#addeventlistenercallback-object-resultobject--subscriptionobject), you need to use the returned `SubscriptionObject` to remove the subscription. Try the following

```js
const playSound = async (url) => {
  try {
    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const sound = SoundPlayer.addEventListener(
        "FinishedPlaying",
        ({ success }) => resolve(sound)
      );
    });

    SoundPlayer.playSoundFile(url, "mp3");
    const sound = await promise;
    SoundPlayer.stop();
    sound.remove();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(`cannot play the sound file`, e);
  }
};
```

Comment: @ScottMarcus The one you linked doesn't, but he's using a library where it does.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Wasn't necessary to remove your comments, it's no shame to look at the wrong docs! :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I now see what I was doing wrong. Your solution works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

An event handler is set up by passing a **reference** to a function. It can then only be removed by passing the **exact same reference**. If you've set up the handler with an anonymous function, then by definition, there is no way to reference it later. Only named functions can be removed.

Exmaple:

```js
function handler(){
  console.log("you invoked the handler");
}

document.getElementById("main").addEventListener("click", handler);

document.getElementById("remove").addEventListener("click", function(){
  document.getElementById("main").removeEventListener("click", handler);
});
```

```html
<button id="main">Click Me</button>

<button id="remove">Remove Handler</button>
```